# Unable to do property injection using Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac-configuration

I am new to autofac. I am trying to do property injection using this IoC container.  The following is my code. I am getting error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

At this line: .
`return _salary.employeeSalary`; in the `GetSalary(int employeeId)` method. In the Program class I even tried, `build.RegisterType<Employee>().WithProperty("_salary", new Salary{ employeeId = 5, employeeSalary = 500 });`

```
public interface IEmployee
{
    double GetSalary(int employeeId);
}
public interface ISalary
{
    int employeeId { get; set; }
    double employeeSalary { get; set; }
}
public class Salary : ISalary
{
    public int employeeId {get; set;}
    public double employeeSalary { get; set; }
}

public class Employee: IEmployee
{
    public ISalary _salary;        

    public double GetSalary(int employeeId)
    {
        if (employeeId == 5)
        {
            return _salary.employeeSalary;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         var build = new ContainerBuilder();
         build.RegisterType<Salary>().As<ISalary>();
         build.RegisterType<Salary>().As<ISalary>().PropertiesAutowired();               
         var container = build.Build();
         Employee employee = container.Resolve<Employee>();

         Console.WriteLine(employee.GetSalary(5));
         Console.ReadLine();            
     }
}
```

Comment: I'll give you a tip. `_salary` is **not** a property. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property?rq=1

Comment: @SilentTremor Property injection definitely **will** work in Autofac (I've used it many times). And no, `public ISalary _salary;` isn't a property. It is a field. This isn't a point of debate. It **is not** a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1:

In order to get `Property Injection` to work with properties, pay attention that the `_salary` is a **field**, and what you need to configure it as a **Property** .

In addition @ehasanul-hoque [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54284781/6844481), you can modify the `_salary` field to be private and add a public property like (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295109/6844481) for more details):

```
private ISalary _salary;

public ISalary Salary
{
    get
    {
        return this._salary;
    }
    set
    {
        _salary = this.value;
    }
}
```

### Option 2:

If you still does not want to convert it to a property, you may use `Method Injection`, by adding a `SetSalary` method like:

```
public class Employee: IEmployee
{
    private ISalary _salary;

    public void SetSalary(ISalary salary)
    {
        this._salary = salary;
    }
}
```

And the builder may looks like:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Salary>().As<ISalary>();
builder.RegisterType<Employee>()
    .OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs<Employee> e) =>
    {
        var salary = e.Context.Resolve<ISalary>();
        e.Instance.SetSalary(salary);
    });

var container = build.Build();
Employee employee = container.Resolve<Employee>();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define your property like below

```
public ISalary _salary { get; set; }
```

Then the below code will work for you

```
var build = new ContainerBuilder();
// build.RegisterType<Salary>().As<ISalary>();
build.RegisterType<Salary>().As<ISalary>();
build.RegisterType<Employee>().As<IEmployee>().PropertiesAutowired();
var container = build.Build();
IEmployee employee = container.Resolve<IEmployee>();

Console.WriteLine(employee.GetSalary(5));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

Create  a constructor in Employee

```
    public Employee(ISalary salary)
    {
        _salary = salary;
    }
```

Register Employee like this

```
build.RegisterType<Employee>().As<IEmployee>()
            .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(ISalary), "salary"));
```

Resolve it like this

```
var employee = container.Resolve<IEmployee>(new NamedParameter("salary",
                new Salary { employeeId = 5, employeeSalary = 500 }));
```

Comment: Hi Prashanth. Thanks for your suggestion. I have already implemented the constructor injection. I want to do it through property injection.